# How can I run script automatically after Docker container startup without altering main process of container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-entrypoint

I have a Docker container which runs a web service. *After* the container process is started, I need to run a single command. How can I do this automatically, either by using Docker Compose or Docker?

I'm looking for a solution that does *not* require me to substitute the original container process with a Bash script that runs `sleep infinity` etc. Is this even possible?

Comment: Have you tried to use `command` directive in the `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: It’s not possible unless designed this way in the entrypoint.

Comment: Do you want your webservice to have process id 1? If not, you can make a script that first runs the single command and then starts your webserver.

Comment: @Maaike, I wish this was an option, but as stated in the question, the command must be run *after* the web service has started.

Comment: @Magnus Then still you can use a script to start the webserver and then run your command, but that is only possible if the webserver does not need to have process id 1. You can just launch a script instead of your webserver. The script launches the webserver, waits until the webserver is started and ready, and then runs the command. But your script will then have process id 1, which is not always a problem, but good to be aware of.

Comment: @Maaike, I know. Regrettably, it's not an option for my particular use case. My Docker image is fed into a third party black box platform, and the web server process needs id 1. Or at the very least, it must be guaranteed that the Docker container dies when the web server dies. I know I could make some hacky script that tries to detect this state, but rather than go that path, I'm going to attack the problem from some other angle entirely.